# Convert String into Date android?

Tags: android, date

I have an app in which I got a date from the server in String format But I need to convert it to a format as "dd-mm-yyyy HH: mm".How do I archive let me know I have tried below mentioned the code.

code:

```
String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        String month = String.valueOf(date.getMonth());
        Log.e(TAG,"Date:"+date);
        Log.e(TAG,"Month:"+month);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);
```

But I am getting in format "Wed May 15 10:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013"

Answer (score 0):

Use the JodaTime package from http://www.joda.org/joda-time/. 
Then:

```
String dateString = "yourDateString";
DateTime date = new DateTime(dateString);
date.toString("dd-mm-yyyy HH: mm", Locale.getDefault()); // Will print the date in the pattern you just specified
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String dateString =  "2018-01-24T05:00:00.000Z"; 

formatTimeFromString1(dateString);

private String formatTimeFromString1 (String dateString) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" ); 
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
            return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should solve the issue. If you need a specific timezone, you can set it at the target formatter:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy HH: mm");
    //targetFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(targetFormat.format(sourceFormat.parse(strDate)));;
```

Comment: out put 15-00-2013 17: 00

Comment: I think there was a typo in the target format? Shall we replace "dd-mm-yyyy HH: mm" -> "dd-MM-yyyy HH: mm"?

Comment: now getting 15-05-2018 22: 30 in which date is correct but time is not....after replacing dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm

Comment: As for the time, perhaps you can check if date has same timezone offset (-7) as the string date. You may enforce it using the commented line, with the appropiate timezoneId